# How to solve the Diophantine equation $x^4 + 2x^3 -3x^2-4x-y^2-2y-6=0$?

Tags: arithmetic, diophantine-equations, factoring

How can one solve the following Diophantine equation in $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$?

$$x^4 + 2x^3 -3x^2-4x-y^2-2y-6=0$$

Comment: The tag "Arithmetics" would have been helpful...

Comment: We may rewrite this as $\,(x^2+x-5)(x^2+x+1)=(y+1)^2$ i.e. $N\,(N+6)=M^2$ with $N:=x(x+1)$. An idea to start at least...

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Definitely helps. $(y+1)^2$ is a square : in other words, a product of two numbers equal to each other . On the other hand , $(x^2+x-5)(x^2+x+1)$ is a product of two numbers that don't differ by more than $6$ : in other words, their greatest common divisor is also heavily restricted. I believe you have found the key to the problem. (Just saw the edit : will put [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%28t-5%29%28t%2B1%29+%3D+y%5E2+over+the+integers) across as validation of the same)

Comment: (little error in my edit : $N:=x(x+1)-5$)  Thanks for the comment @SarveshRavichandranIyer and neat result by Alpha! Cheers,

Comment: To make it even more symmetric $$(x(x+1)-2)^2=(y+1)^2+3^2$$ $$(\pm 3)^2=0^2+3^2$$ $$(\pm 5)^2=(\pm 4)^2+3^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a Diophantine equation, we only seek for integer solutions. Notice that $x^4 + 2x^3 -3x^2-4x-y^2-2y-6=0$ implies $(y-x^2-x+3)(y+x^2+x-1)=-9$, we only have $6$ cases: $((y-x^2-x+3),(y+x^2+x-1))$ must be one of $(1,-9),(9,-1),(3,-3),(-1,9),(-9,1),(-3,3)$. However, after checking all these cases there are no solutions.

A simpler way to do this: modulo 4, we have

$$x^4 + 2x^3 -3x^2-4x-y^2-2y-6\equiv x^4 + 2x^3 +x^2-y^2-2y+2\equiv (x(x+1))^2-(y+1)^2+3\equiv 3-(y+1)^2$$

However, $3-(y+1)^2$ won't be zero modulo $4$ since the squares must be $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$, not $3$.

Comment: $(y-x^2-x+3)(y+x^2+x-1)=-9$

Comment: Thank you for pointing out! I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

$x^4 + 2x^3 -3x^2-4x-y^2-2y-6=0\iff(x^2+x)^2-4(x^2+x)=(y+1)^2+5$

Putting $X=x^2+x$ we get $(X-2)^2=(y+1)^2+9$ whose only solutions are clearly
$$(X-2,y+1)=(\pm3,0),(\pm5,\pm4)$$ in both cases, since $X=x^2+x$, we have the equations for the unknown $x$
$$x^2+x-5=0\text{ and } x^2+x+1=0\\x^2+x-7=0\text{ and } x^2+x+3=0$$ these four equations have not integral roots, consequently the diophantine equation $x^4 + 2x^3 -3x^2-4x-y^2-2y-6=0$ has no solution.